# Not able to Show Icons in Tablayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, material-design, android-tablayout

I am trying to show icons in my tab, I am using tablayout and viewpager , but when I m calling tablayout.setupWithViewPager(viewpager) my icons are disappearing 
Min sdk is 16 
Target is 24
Support library 24.2.1

this is how I am setting my Tabs :-

```
    private void setUpTabs(){
       tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewpager);

        TabLayout.Tab discoverTab = tabs.newTab();
        TabLayout.Tab placesTab = tabs.newTab();
        TabLayout.Tab rewardTab = tabs.newTab();

        Drawable discover = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.discover);
        discover.setAlpha(255);
        discover.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        Drawable places = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.places);
        places.setAlpha(55);
        places.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        Drawable rewards = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.rewards);
        rewards.setAlpha(55);
        rewards.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

        discoverTab.setIcon(discover);
        placesTab.setIcon(places);
        rewardTab.setIcon(rewards);

        tabs.addTab(discoverTab,0);
        tabs.addTab(placesTab,1);
        tabs.addTab(rewardTab,2); 
    }
```

ViewPager :-

```
   private void setUpViewPager(){
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(DiscoverFragment.getFragment(null),"Discover");
        adapter.addFrag(PlacesFragment.getFragment(null),"Places");
        adapter.addFrag(RewardsFragment.getFragment(null),"Rewards");
        viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

ViewPagerAdapter :-

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        // return null to display only the icon
        return null;
    }
}
```

my XML layout :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/action_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="?attr/colorAccent"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/black" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: can you share the code

Comment: @UmarAta please check now

Comment: try to replace this adapter.addFrag(DiscoverFragment.getFragment(null),"Discover"); with adapter.addFrag(DiscoverFragment.getFragment(null),""); then share result

Answer (score 5):

Just try this way it will work for you

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.ic_tab_favourite,
            R.drawable.ic_tab_call,
            R.drawable.ic_tab_contacts
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();
    }

    private void setupTabIcons() {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFrag(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
        adapter.addFrag(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

For more check [Tablayout](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/)

Comment: which support library u are using ?

Comment: check complete example in link